# Trying to Call a Webservice, not getting the returned json object works in PHP

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call a webservice thatussses. the uri tell what service and the header contains a signed message for authentication. For now I'm putting in NA for the athencation cade.  The web service documention gives examples in PHP, whitch reutrns a JSON object with a error message.  My java code does not return a json object and has a string 
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2017 20:05:0....."

Java Code to call webservice

```
    Calendar Time = Calendar.getInstance();     
    long TimeToNumber=Time.getTimeInMillis();
    String nonce=Long.toString(TimeToNumber);       

    String uri=
   "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey="+apikey+
    "&nonce="+nonce;

    try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

    httpPost.addHeader("apisign:" , "na");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    // display jason object returned by web service
    System.out.println(response);
    } catch ( Exception  e) {
        print(e.getMessage();
    }
```

PHP Sample Code

```
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$ch = curl_init($uri);
// Put na for sign should get a error mess in return json object
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'."na"));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
echo( $execResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should have
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
          }
to get result from response
so code looks like
        try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

```
    httpPost.addHeader("apisign:" , "na");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
      }


    } catch ( Exception  e) {
        ted++;
    }
```